# Software recommendations for PDF layout review

Tags: software-recommendation

What I'm looking for is a tool (online/offline) to create reviews for layouts (in my case: mobile applications layouts) - i.e. make comments/annotations for graphic designer that would be assigned to a view (PDF's page).

The perfect solution would also allow me to make comments for certain areas of a PDF, f.e. comment for an image acting as a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat Pro or Adobe Acrobat Standard both have a commenting feature which allows you to annotate any PDF and save the annotations.

Comment: I found that this feature has to be enabled first. Something like "extend functionality".

Comment: The newest version of Adobe Reader, 'Adobe Reader X', also has this functionality, for free.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, I find myself by-passing even Acrobat more and more and using the Apple Preview tool. They have pretty impressive PDF annotation capabilities these days as well.

Comment: Be aware, Preview does not show all elements of some PDFs. There may be missing items in Preview which you aren't even aware of.